# UpdateInstallationDisk

Tags: system-installation

How to create a install disk (USB) that has libraries loaded like:libftdi-dev,libsqlite3-dev,libxml2-dev,libmicrohttpd-dev,libncurses5-dev e.t.c. for application development. (The *.so files are essential for the applications developed)
So It sounds like what I need to do is:

1. make a disk-image that will fit within all destination disks
2. have a boot capable version of Ubuntu on a USB.
3. have a command to partition the destination disk sized to the disk-image
4. auto copy disk-image onto the destination
   Can this work?  What problems will I run into?

Comment: Perhaps using an image file will work for you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-dupliate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution

Comment: @karel:Which post on that page do you recommend. If the OP reads all of them he will have wasted a lot of time. None of the apps are supported with 20.04 or 20.10, they have all been abandoned, Remastersys is still recommended on that page and it was abandoned in 2012.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I recommend [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307835/) and I also upvoted it.

Comment: @karel: Thank you. I am hesitant to vote to close the Question you linked to, lot of good historical stuff there. Just not much of contemporary value. perhaps someday  Fragadelic will bring Remastersys out of retirement.