# How to make an IMG / ISO of preinstalled Windows 10 for use with VirtualBox

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, windows-10

I have purchased a computer that comes with pre-installed *Windows 10*.  I am wanting to run *Ubuntu Studio 20.04* desktop and setup *Windows 10* as a gust operating system using *VirtualBox*.

What I think I'm seeing is that I need *Windows 10* in the form of an ISO when configuring *VirtualBox*.  Then I use *Windows 10* this way.

Can anyone provide me with a list of steps to accomplish this?

(Just to be clear:  I am not needing *Windows 10* to be listed in Grub as a possible operating system.  I've got along fine without it for the past 5 years.  This is just to give me the option to use it for a few minutes for a specific task.)

Comment: You can create an image file, (.img), of your Windows using Disks on a Live Ubuntu USB, then you can convert the image file to a .vdi file and use that in VBox. Sort of the opposite of what I did in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution

Comment: I will try this @C.S.Cameron

Comment: Let me know how it goes or if I can help.