# (Question) Bootable Ubuntu flash-drive with programs

Tags: boot, package-management, system-installation, usb-drive

As part of my job, I install between 2 to 7 Ubuntu machines per day. (18/20 & Desktop/Server)
After installing the OS, I need to install a few things like VLC, Net-Tools, and openssh-server.

Is there a way to create a bootable disk that includes these programs already? Or one that will install them automatically after the Ubuntu installations?

Comment: Install from an image file: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution

Answer (score 0):

### Using Image File to Clone Operating System

An image file is a quick reliable way to clone an OS.

**1) Create Image file from existing operating system:**

- Boot Live Ubuntu USB and insert Full install, (or Persistent), USB to be copied.
- Create an image file of the Full install USB, (or Persistent USB), using Gnome-Disks from the Live USB.

[image]

[image]

**2) Install Image File to target drive**

**Caution: The target drive will be overwritten**.

- Use the pancake icon in Disks or use Etcher, Rufus, dd or mkusb, when you want to restore or clone the image to another drive.

For mass production, Etcher can flash an image to multiple disks at the same time.

[image]

Note that cloned disks use the same UUID, GParted has an option to create new UUID's if you like.

For more information see: [How to Duplicate a Ubuntu System for Distribution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution)