# can I reinstall Ubuntu 20.10 with all settings, apps and themes?

Tags: backup, restore, reinstall

I set up the ubuntu 20.10 system perfectly for myself and installed some software. And can I keep the system I’m using right now to reinstall or give it to someone else?
is it possible. can I reinstall Ubuntu 20.10 with all settings, apps and themes?

Comment: All of the alternatives listed in the Duplicated post are obsolete and just a waste of the OP's time. **No 1 answer is remastersys?** give us a break.

Comment: Use Gnome-Disks, (three line icon, upper right), to **Create a Disk Image**. you can restore this clone image to another disk using Rufus, Etcher, Disks, SDC or mkusb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Clone Ubuntu 20.10 with all Settings, Apps and Themes?

From a Live USB, use Gnome-Disks, (three line icon, upper right), to **Create a Disk Image** of your perfect drive on a Flash drive, SSD or HDD of adequate size. (All data on the disk will be overwritten).

You can restore this clone image to another disk using Rufus, Etcher, Disks, SDC or mkusb.

For more details see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1300542/43926

Comment: thank you bro, I will to try this method