# How to clone system boot disk to new attached disk

Tags: server, clone, disk-management

Currently I have 350G size of disk. But 75G only used.
I attached new additional disk 100G in GCP.
I want to clone the 75G (boot and data) to new 100G to minimize cost.

What are the commands to be used?

Comment: Use GParted from Live USB to shrink source partition to <100GB. Use GParted to copy/paste source partition to new 100GB disk. Install GRUB2 bootloader to 100GB disk. Edit new /boot/grub/grub.cfg to suit UUID etc.

Comment: can I do this even if my 350G is used as my boot system?

Comment: *Use GParted from **live USB*** is the key.

Comment: You need to do the GParted work from a Live USB. You can't shrink a partition that you are booted from.

Comment: If you tell me whether  you boot in Legacy mode or UEFI mode, I will post a step by step answer, if legacy see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1338204/43926

Comment: So, I already manage to clone the disk by using weresync, but the 100G disk that I want to use as a boot disk in my VM instance (GCP) won't boot.