# How to make an iso image of linux machine

Tags: boot, usb, backup

Ok so basically I wipe my machine a lot. And I take about an hour to reinstall Linux and reinstall/uninstall all my programs. It would be nice to just load Linux with all my preferences already there.

Is there a way to do this? I’ve tried DD and it seems to use my ENTIRE hard drive (even empty parts of the drive).

Comment: This isn't a Linux support site (SE *Unix & Linux* performs that function), so why ask here?  As written I don't see your question as on-topic (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Creating an image file might be a good alternative to an ISO file, See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution. You can also use Gnome-Disks, (or dd), to create and restore an image file of a single partition,

Answer (score 0):

You can use higher level programs such as [fsarchiver](https://www.fsarchiver.org/), or partimage to backup or restore Linux partitions, which will only copy the data. They can also compress the data during the backup process. See https://www.fsarchiver.org/partimage/ for a comparison between the two.