# Create Ubuntu Installation USB or DVD from my current Ubuntu Installation with all my apps/settings etc

Tags: system-installation, usb, dvd, clone

I have an operating Ubuntu installation and I would like to create an installation USB or DVD that will include all my apps and settings from my current installation. Is this possible?

Ubuntu version 18.04 LTS

It seems RemasterSys is abandonned?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1341696/1222991) might give you what you need. Alternatively, there's [this option](https://askubuntu.com/a/1300542/1222991) which will create an image of your current installation.

Comment: I do it with images rather than with ISO's, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution . Oops, this refers to the same method matigo suggests.