# How to convert Ubuntu VirtualBox VM to .iso format?

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, iso, live-cd

I have configured Ubuntu 20.04 in VirtualBox. I have installed some software and applied some settings.

Now, I want to convert this image to a `.iso` image so that I can install this customized Ubuntu version to other servers.

How can I do it?

Comment: You may find it easier to convert the VDI file to IMG and install that, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution

Comment: @guiverc The duplicated question makes no mention about converting a VirtualBox VDI file to a bootable ISO file as the OP asked for.