# Create N bootable copies of Ubuntu system on SSD drives

Tags: boot, system-installation, ssd, external-hdd

I need to create multiple copies of the same system i.e. I want to set up 30 SSD drives with Ubuntu 18.04 with some preinstalled features there such as ROS etc

I set up the environment on my local machine and now I wanna create an .iso image with this settings and files and populate ;) SSD drives.

I tried:
I using `dd if of` but without success.
Issues: disk is not bootable and DD also creates image of 500gb (even though 480gb is an empty space...).

I saw some tutorials to set up bootable Ubuntu (empty one) which requires a lot of processes and would take a bunch of time...

My main question are:
How to correctly create .iso file of the environment (with only necessary files) and what is the command/bash script (does not have to be complete) to set up the SSD drive with Ubuntu system on it from the terminal using that .iso image.

I would appreciate any help tips.

Comment: Do you need to make ISO files? Using an image file to duplicate the SSD's might be easier: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution Etcher can create multiple bootable USB's at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can be useful for the future

1. Create an Ubuntu bootable SSD disk or Pendrive
2. Boot from this external disk.
3. Create an image of your system. I is usually (or always) impossible to do it when you are using the system since you have to unmount the disk you are creating an image of, at least this was my case.
4. Plug another disk, and using `dd` command copy the image onto that disk.
5. Now you have an image on the disk but there may be some issues with proper partitioning, location and root. Follow this tutorial to fix it

https://www.dionysopoulos.me/making-a-portable-full-installation-of-ubuntu-on-a-usb-hdd.html

6. Create an image of that disk.
7. Now you can copy it on the other SSD drives, creating correct partition tables. In my case it was necessary to unmount the disks I connected first, before copying it.

   `sudo umount /dev/sdX/ # or often sdX3`