# how to make an iso image of ubuntu22.04

Tags: 22.04, iso

I wannna to make an ISO image of the current system (ubuntu22.04) and put it on the usb for easy installation on other devices,I search some tools but no longer maintained.

Comment: That is not how this works. You download an ISO, open it and add software or settings you want for your install and burn that ISO. I would advice against it as it takes A LOT of time it get correct. It is FAR FAR easier to use a normal ISO, then create a script of all your changes and execute that after install. Every setting has a command line method. Every software you install or remove also has a command line method.

Comment: I would recommend using [Cubic (Custom Ubuntu ISO Creator)](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic) that allows you to customize the ISO and create your own with your own modifications added.

Comment: Dell Recovery can do it on Dell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd). Specifically [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/49679)

Comment: You should perform a normal install, then restore the packages and user files. You can refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools.

Comment: What you want may be easier using an IMG file than an ISO file, See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution