# make custom iso of ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, lubuntu, customization, automation

The one thing I want to do is customize Ubuntu to make my own ISO file installation, and one of the things I want to do is enable eno1 (my 1G interface) after installation! Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: The Ethernet cable interface (eno1) is detected and enabled automatically if there is a cable connection to a working network when you boot from the Live USB. It is not clear what customization you want. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1424166/edit) and explain more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: "Do you know if this is possible?" yes it is but please do not ask yes/no questions. There is really no added value when you do :) Start with reading up about "autoinstall" and YAML.  Ask a question when you run into an error and keep searching on how to do this. start here: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall

Comment: Yes.  (it's possible)   *your question is answered; but you gave no details as to if you looked at the documentation Ubuntu has for doing what you want, and what you don't understand with it, or where you got stuck.  Ubuntu uses five different installers, you've tagged Lubuntu thus `calamares` which differs to most of Ubuntu (Lubuntu & one other flavor only use `calamares`) and that is **not** a server installer/distribution*

Comment: It is easier to make a .IMG file to use for installation than a .ISO file: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution

Comment: That's great!
user68186 said the interface is automatically detected and enabled, but in my case it wasn't.
The solution from rinzwind doesn't help me either!
I'm looking for something like Cubic that can give me an ISO file and enable ENO1 after installation as well as get my IP address from my DHCP server!