# Make an image backup of OS and create bootable media with it?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, backup, themes

I should note that this is for Ubuntu KDE 22.04, so some of the tools I see mentioned in posts about the subject haven't really worked.

Basically, I made a lot of theme changes to my new Kubuntu machine (installations through Kvantum, Themes Manager, or even imported icons). I really like the feel of the machine, so I want to take what I just made and directly implement it to other devices without having to go through the arduous process of installing/configuring these themes on several other computers. This should be fairly doable, since I've only used ~20 GB of storage on my riced machine.

I'd like to know if there's a quick way for me to copy my Kubuntu device and filesystem so that I can create a bootable device to flash other machines with. Instead of starting from scratch on the new machines, I'll already have the themes and files installed and configured.

One thing I'd like to note to is that Clonezilla has given me a lot of trouble when it comes to backing up my device. Not sure if this is something on my end or soemthing relating to Kubuntu, but in any case I'd rpefer avoiding clonezilla if at all possible.

Comment: This works for me, How to Duplicate a Ubuntu System for Distribution?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution

Comment: Too bad Clonezilla doesn't work for you; this is exactly what it's for and it's one of the tools I would really hate to be without.

Comment: I suggest new install and restore from your normal backup. The backup should include everything you need as when your drive fails you have everything you need. At minimum, you backup /home & list of installed apps. If you have server apps those are in / and separately backed up. And maybe some settings in /etc, But only use for reference. I edit grub and copy those changes into /home so backed up. All your user settings are in /home in the hidden . folders like /home/$USER/.config.