# What is the best and easiest software recommended for creating a custom Ubuntu Live Image that is installable?

Tags: 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04, added apps, created folders and added data.
Now, I would like to back up my customized OS as a USB Live Image.

If my customized OS becomes corrupt, I'd like to use the USB Live Image to reinstall the customized OS.

I've searched google, but there are so many questionable choices.

I was using Systemback for Ubuntu 16.04 and it was great, but it does not work for Ubuntu versions greater than 16.04.

Is there a recommended tool or software that makes it easy to do the above in 2022?

Comment: Also note that in a year or so Ubuntu 18.04 will reach its end of life. Moreover, "best and easiest" are opinion based criteria. What is easy for me may be very hard for you. Questions that see opinions are off-topic in this question answer site. This is a question answer site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Duplicate a Ubuntu System for Distribution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best and easiest software recommended for creating a custom Ubuntu Live Image that is installable?

There really is no such thing. What you ask here is a task for a backup solution not a custom live session.

> I was using Systemback for Ubuntu 16.04 and it was great, but it does not work for Ubuntu versions greater than 16.04.

How about timeshift ? Should do the same as Systemback.

> Is there a recommended tool or software that makes it easy to do the above in 2022?

My experience: use a normal live session. Altering a live session is time consuming and is only limited usable. A live session only has a lifespan of a couple of months or years. Plus if you change your mind you need to redo that live session.

My setup:

I have 2 disks: ssd and hdd. My ssd holds `/` and includes `/home/`. My hdd holds all the directories that are created in `/home/$USER`. Every time I reinstall my ssd gets formatted as I have zero personal files on that disk. My hdd gets mounted as `/discworld/`

I have a script that has a lot of lines and looks like this (1 example of each different options):

```
# directories set to /discworld/
cp /discworld/Documents/user-dirs.dirs ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
# apt 
apt update 
apt install vlc smplayer tweaks 
# gsettings
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'nothing'
```

(and so on; if you use it the backup directory could also hold a backup of for instance browser settings, archived mails etc).

During the time I use an Ubuntu version I install more software or test different settings. And each of those installs I add to the script. When I reinstall I remove those I did install but did not use that often.

I even had a time where I had 2 or 3 of those scripts each for a complete different setup.

When a new LTS is released things often change: different defaults, new or deleted gsettings options. Unity that got deleted, systemd got introduced. Or maybe I changed my mind about some software I want as my default. It is far quicker to open this script and alter it.

It has been my method for at least the last 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no particular reason to use a Live CD other than make the installation "easier". You can use a tool like [redorescue](http://redorescue.com/) to fully backup your system to an external storage and restore it to your computer.