# Can't install Remastersys on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, kde, bug-reporting, remastersys

I want to install Remastersys on my personal computer, also that can't install.

**1.** I used PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxthebest.net/remastersys
```

**2.** I updated packages:

```
sudo apt update
```

**3.** I installed Remastersys and can't work:

```
sudo apt install remastersys-gtk
```

I want it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We have been updating a fork of Remastersys for several years now,
> called [Wasta-Remastersys](https://www.wastalinux.org/home/customizing/wasta-remastersys/)
>
> Note that we removed the GUI for creating an ISO, but it can run in
> "dist" (don't save user settings, instead be ready for distributing to
> others) or "backup" mode (save your settings, etc). Also note that the
> ISO specification is limited to 4GB in size: if the resulting ISO is
> larger then there will be a failure.
>
> We have added features from Pinguy Builder, etc. to make sure it runs
> in UEFI mode, can install broadcom drivers offline, etc.
>
> Good luck! It has served us well over the years.

rik-shaw

From: [How to Duplicate a Ubuntu System for Distribution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. That PPA is not available for 20.04.

Remastersys and its forks haven't been available this decade.

Answer (score 2):

Remastersys has not been updated since June 2018 (more than four years ago), and the latest version is made for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, "Bionic".

I suggest that you look for a newer tool, for example **Cubic**. Search the internet for **linux cubic**.

Comment: Here is the [Cubic site](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki).