# Can I make a bootable installation .iso file from my current PC state?

Tags: backup, iso, brasero

Is it possible to make an ISO of my current installation, flash it to a pendrive and use it as an installer for another PC? Will it have all my files and apps in it? Do I have to put an installer in it?

Comment: I'll differ to the answer @NMath has provided, BUT it requires setup before hand as you won't be using a *normal* install, but can be used as a *normal* install (*as I understand, do note I've never done it & just read blogs by folks who do it*). As example, the creator (*Jacques*) of Makulu Linux blogged about the script he used that created an ISO of his own machine where he tweaked his modified Ubuntu system and created the Makulu Linux ISOs that people downloaded and installed. My reference is years old, but many have blogged on how to do it, but it may involve change/setup to your install

Comment: Similar to guiverc's link but also creates a self contained installer USB: https://askubuntu.com/a/1300542/43926