# creating iso with installed linux where home data also should be part of iso

Tags: iso

I am looking out for a tool which will help to create an iso from installed linux virtual machine where it will also include home folder and can help to create bootable iso.

I have searched on web a lot and many tools do not support like customizer, systembackup, respin, clonezilla etc. I have installed pinguybuilder but with several options though it created iso but it after installation of iso it could not install bootloader.

Is there any tool available on Ubuntu 18.4/20.4/22.4 to create bootable iso of installed linux.

Comment: The creator of Makulu Linux (*Jacque Montague Rayner*) blogged about the tool he used when he switched to Makulu Linux from Debian to Ubuntu, and how he created the Makulu ISOs. He was publishing the script he used; which created the ISO from a system he used/modified for releasing, and its one place I may look  (*or others that have done it as there are many!*).

Comment: Creating it from a end-user system will not be the same as a Ubuntu ISO in that there are variations of what gets installed; eg. I can install the same Lubuntu ISO (*on thumb-drive*) on two different boxes (one BIOS, one uEFI) and the install isn't identical; as the boot process will differ between those boxes that the installer adjusts for the box (I'm using Lubuntu as example only; but an installed system isn't the same as a pre-installed *live* Ubuntu ISO).

Comment: Not sure how to do it with an Iso file but it is possible to do what you want using .img files and .vdi files. see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1300542/43926