# Is it possible to revert to my previous Ubuntu_Mate version on my computer

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-mate

I have Release 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) 64-bit. Ubuntu_Mate

This version with my AMD hardware has some bugs that are very irritating.

I have made many posts about it.

It concerns the file managers, both Caja and Thunar.

I am NOT interested in expending any more effort on this version.

Is there a way to make a disk image so I can revert to it if the next version also has those same bugs?

I would prefer help from users who have actually done so.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Duplicate a Ubuntu System for Distribution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution). Of course, your goal is not redistribution. But that seems unimportant; the means are identical.

Comment: I could find no Gnome-Disks.

Comment: `gnome-disk-utility | 42.0-1ubuntu1           | jammy          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` is the gnome-disks utility.  You can non-destructively re-install a system i wrote about this answer - https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533 which I'm about to use to revert a *noble* system (with issue) to *jammy*

Comment: @guiverc gnome-disk-utility command not found

Comment: I provided the package name (*partial result of a `rmadison` enquiry*) in my prior comment; the command that runs it is `gnome-disks`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/gnome-disk-utility/filelist  *partial answer to your not finding gnome-disks comment being the reason it was mentioned*

Comment: Years ago, when using Windows, folks at my company would make a mess of their company computer(Me included.) The I.T. guys would come with a CD or DVD and restore the system. I think Linux is very good, but what happened to "keeping it simple.?"

Comment: @fixit7 Did the GNOME disks method work?

Comment: @Archisman Panegrahi I decided to forgo using GNOME disks method. Too many steps for me.